# Problems running raw powershell code from inside python

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

Suppose I have the following script:

```
import os,sys,subprocess
mypwr_shell_code = '''
function test_args()
{
  echo "heres arg 0: $($args[0])"
  echo "heres arg 1: $($args[1])"
  echo "heres arg 2: $($args[2])"
  echo "heres arg 3: $($args[3])"
  echo "heres arg 4: $($args[4])"
  echo "heres arg 5: $($args[5])"
  echo "heres arg 6: $($args[6])"
  echo "heres arg 7: $($args[7])"
  echo "heres arg 8: $($args[8])"
  echo "heres arg 9: $($args[9])"
  echo "heres arg 10: $($args[10])"
}

test_args $args

"================================================"
date
"================================================"
pwd
"================================================"
dir getprocesses.ps1
"================================================"
'''
```

How do i run this code in python, without having to write the code to disk?

I have tried this:

```
results = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "-NonInteractive", "-EncodedCommand", mypwr_shell_code], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(results)
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\J\solid.py", line 3704, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "-NonInteractive", "-EncodedCommand", mypwr_shell_code], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 206] The filename or extension is too long
```

I also tried:

```
print ( os.system('iex "%s"' % (mypwr_shell_code) ) )
```

This resulted in a `-1`.

Note, the code in `mypwr_shell_code` can be far more complex than what is shown here.

My ask here is how to run a powershell code (which is stored in a variable), from within python.

Please kindly advise.

Comment: Try saving your powershell code to a file then using `Popen` to run that file.